# BlackBerry Java SDK 5.0.0.25 plugin on Eclipse Helios SR2

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6

I installed the BlackBerry Java SDK 5.0.0.25 on Helios SR2, via `www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java` update site. Smooth installation, sure, but I can't see any BlackBerry menu in `Preferences` or in `New project` dialog.

The RIM logo correctly appears in Eclipse About and clicking it I can see its info correctly shown.

I tried to create a new workspace, too, because this helped me with BlackBerry stand-alone version of JDE, but no result.

My Eclipse already starts with `-clean` parameter.

Do you experienced similar problems about it?

Comment: Looking on how many devs are complaining on Eclipse plugin I've got an impression the plugin is still in some sort of a beta state. Too many issues for a production level tool. So I still use Eclipse for coding + JDE for building/debugging. This pair works just nice.

Comment: @Arhimed Would you clarify the concept? Do you open Eclipse, then JDE, both pointing to the same project? Then you jump from one to another coding in one and building in the other? :)

Comment: @Giorgio Vespucci: yes, I have both JDE and Eclipse opened at the same time. They both are pointed to the same folder where JDE's project files and Eclipse project files are placed. They share the same code. So after I've edited in Eclipse, then I build in the JDE.

Comment: @Ahrimed When I tried to open Eclipse vs. the workspace already opened with JDE it said me "Workspace in use or cannot be created". Are you using different workspace, don't you?

Comment: @Giorgio Vespucci: what do you mean under the "workspace"?

Comment: @Ahrimed "Workspace" in Eclipse terminology. Please see http://goo.gl/q8dkX, "Selecting a workspace" section.

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading the full IDE with the plugin already installed http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp

Refer to this forum [post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Java-plug-in-for-Eclipse-3-6-not-showing-BlackBerry-App/td-p/1046735)

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882024/why-blackberry-simulators-hang-on-jde-1-3-0-6-0-0-30-java-sdk. I already done it :) Reading the post it seems that installing the plugin onto Helios is discouraged! OK, BlackBerry, then do not distribute it!